# Having trouble inputting a single node into my singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, scanf, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I am creating a singly linked list with just a single node and I am having some trouble with getting it to work as I want it to. When I enter the information I want to place in the list I am getting my last piece of data to append to the previous one without my doing. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxName 30
#define maxID 10
#define maxAge 3

typedef struct node
{
    char fName[maxName];
    char lname[maxName];
    char PUID[maxID];
    char age[maxAge];
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *head = NULL;

//This function will create a list with just a single node and the data to the list must be passed by paramter
node * createnode(char firstName[], char lastName[], char puid[], char age[])
{
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("Enter the first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &(head -> fName));

    printf("Enter the last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &(head -> lname));

    printf("Enter the PUID: ");
    scanf("%s", &(head -> PUID));

    printf("Enter the Age: ");
    scanf("%s", &(head -> age));

    return head;
}
```

And this is the output I am getting when I enter the information:
JAke,Thomas,789456987525,25->

That 25 is appending to the end of the PUID I enter. Any help you be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: If you want to store a 10-digit id in a char buffer, that buffer should be an array of at least 11 chars, because it needs one for the null terminator. And you should enforce that the user cannot enter more than 10 digits, otherwise the buffer will overflow. That's what has happened in your case.

Comment: If an answer is helpful for you, you should click tick button under voting number.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove address operators.

```
printf("Enter the first name: ");
scanf("%s", (head -> fName));

printf("Enter the last name: ");
scanf("%s", (head -> lname));

printf("Enter the PUID: ");
scanf("%s", (head -> PUID));

printf("Enter the Age: ");
scanf("%s", (head -> age));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function declaration

```
node * createnode(char firstName[], char lastName[], char puid[], char age[]);
```

does not make sense because the parameters are not used in the function.

So the function should be declared like

```
node * createnode( void );
```

Within the function statements like this

```
scanf("%s", &(head -> fName));
           ^^^
```

are incorrect. They must look like

```
scanf("%s", head -> fName);
```

As for the wrong output then it seems you are entering more characters in a character array than it can hold including the terminating zero of string.

For example the entered symbols `7894569875` will be stored in the data member `PUID` like string `"7894569875"` that contains 11 characters (including the terminating zero character) instead of 10.

It is more safe to use the function fgets instead of scanf with the format specifier %s.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...


fgets( head->fName, maxName, stdin );
head->fName[ strcspn( head->fName, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea when a function depends on a global variable. In this case you will be unable for example to have to lists in a program.